# regex matches with intersection in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I wonder if it is possible to get MatchCollection with all matches even if there's intersection among them.

```
string input = "a a a";
Regex regex = new Regex("a a");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
```

This code returns 1, but I want it to return 2. How to achive it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string input = "a a a";
Regex regexObj = new Regex("a a");
Match matchObj = regexObj.Match(input);
while (matchObj.Success) {
    matchObj = regexObj.Match(input, matchObj.Index + 1); 
}
```

will iterate over the string starting the next iteration one character after the position of the previous match, therefore finding all matches.

Comment: Seems like what i need. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Very nice I was going to recommend something similar with string.indexOf assuming that the search string was a vanilla string.  I'm wondering if there's a complex regex that this method wouldn't work for.....hmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a while loop by replacing "a a" by "a" and match it another time against the regex until there is no match.

Comment: This example is simplified. I have much more complex input string and much more complex regex. So your solution won't work in that case. Thanks anyway.